# rake db:migrate not picking up all the fields in my migration file

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dbmigrate

I will be the first to admit that I am probably doing this wrong or have a poor workflow but I am trying to build my first rails app.  It works different in 3 than I recall in rails 1 (last time i putzed around with this).  I remember defining my models and building theDB off that.    So instead I did this:

`$script/generate scaffold post name:string address:text dob:date desire:text interests:text hobby:text signature:text`

Then, it builds some files (views controllers models etc.)  but it builds the migration file.  I have a complex table (above is just an example) and im not going to type out all the fields. So i thought I could do something like the above and then goto the created migreation create file and add the rest of myfields (since that editor is nice than a command line way or from an IDE but using the actual source editor) and do a rake db:migrate and get the database with all the fields.and have it regenerate the scaffold etc...   it does not seem to be doing this, is myworkflow poor?

Comment: this seems to be what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438619/rails-3-adding-fields-to-a-table

Comment: oh editing them isn't a problem.  I was just editing the wrong one it seemed.  Or doing it wrong in general, but I seemed to figure it out.  I wish I could regenerate my scaffolds too cause I added new fields now.  I dont like scaffolding but for some quick and dirty proof of concept its nice.